# Why did Carina Smyth feel lucky to be a woman?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

In *Dead Men Tell No Tales (2017)*, Carina Smyth, disguised as nurse met Henry
who caught by British soldiers by seeing his clothes as marked for treason.

> Carina Smyth: Because I need to get off this island. To solve The Map
>   No Man...
>
> Henry: No Man Can Read. Left by Poseidon himself.
>
> Carina Smyth: You've read the ancient text?
>
> Henry: In each language they were written. But this map has never been
>   seen nor read by any man.
>
> Carina Smyth: **Luckily, I'm a woman**.

Comment: [I am no man!](https://youtu.be/BrCvgiQGh1o?t=7s)

Comment: Sigh. This joke is so old, so painfully obvious every single time it is used, I am stunned to see it used yet again here in 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's the map no man can read. But she's a womam rather than a man, so she presumes she can read it.